# Custom HeaderedContentControl, set header with multibinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding

I'm doing a custom `HeaderedContentControl` which is basically is styled like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:DetailsControl}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <!-- Only if content is string provide a default Template -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                       FontSize="{DynamicResource NormalFontSize}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                           FontWeight="Light"
                           FontSize="{DynamicResource SubHeaderFontSize}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DetailsControlTemplate}" />
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="DetailsControlTemplate"
                 TargetType="{x:Type controls:DetailsControl}">
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"/>

        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This works fine when I'm just setting the Header to a string

```
<controls:DetailsControl Header="Header Text" [...]>
    [...]
</controls:DetailsControl>
```

or a normal binding

```
<controls:DetailsControl Header="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=ElementList}" [...]>
    [...]
</controls:DetailsControl>
```

But when I'm setting the Header to a Multibinding it won't display me anything at all.

```
<controls:DetailsControl [...]>
    <controls:DetailsControl.Header>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
            <Binding ElementName="ElementList" Path="SelectedItem.Name"/>
            <Binding ElementName="ElementList" Path="SelectedItem.Description"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </controls:DetailsControl.Header>

    [...]
</controls:DetailsControl>
```

Where am I doing wrong? What would be the correct way to fix this?

Comment: you should use IMultiValueConverter

Comment: so there is no pure wpf solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

`StringFormat` requires target to be of a `string` type. Since `Header` is a content field try putting it in a `TextBlock`:

```
<controls:DetailsControl.Header>
   <TextBlock>
      <TextBlock.Text>
         <Multibinding .../>
      </TextBlock.Text>
   </TextBlock>
</controls:DetailsControl.Header>
```

Comment: It will work when I'm just using a normal `TextBlock` but not within the Header (I think it's because my default HeaderTemplate is already a textblock, but I would like to keep the default template so I don't have to add a TextBlock to every header)

Comment: But then why use `ContentPresenter` in your `Template`? You accept only `strings` as `Header` so there is no point of using `ContentPresenter`. Normally that would be a job of `ContentPresenter` to generate content but in your case you can put `TextBlock` straight into `Template` without need for `ContentPresenter`

Comment: The normal case is displaying a text header (so I set the default `HeaderTemplate` to this), but what if I want a `Header` with an `Image` and an `TextBlock`? That's why I need a `ContentPresenter`

Comment: Yes, but you explicitly specify in your `ContentPresenter` to use `HeaderTemplate`, which by default is `TextBlock` and that's what `ContentPresenter` will use until you define other template. You don't have to do as it will happen automatically in `ContentPresenter` and then the solution from above should work.

Comment: But I don't only do it because I wan't it to be a `TextBlock` I also specify `FontSize` and `FontWeight` in that `Template`